# Using other bean and method in Spring Security @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to using `@PreAuthorize` with SpEL within Spring Security like the example at http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/100708-spel-and-spring-security-3-accessing-bean-reference-in-preauthorize
but this is not work for me while using it in Spring Security 4.1.4. Below is my sample code:

A bean class:

```java
package com.service.spel;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component(value="accessBean")
public class AccessCheckBean {
    public String getPermision(){
        /**
         * return the api permision
         */
        String scope = "#oauth2.hasScope('resource.Update')";
        return scope;
    }
}
```

In controller:

```java
@PreAuthorize("accessBean.getPermision()")
@GetMapping("/perm")
public @ResponseBody String getPerm(){
    return "Perm";
}
```

Error message:

> Failed to evaluate expression 'accessBean.getPermision()'

Seems I can't use SpEL like above. So if I am using this version of Spring Security, how can I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `@`, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access-web-beans):

> **Referring to Beans in Web Security Expressions**
>
> If you wish to extend the expressions that are available, you can easily refer to any Spring Bean you expose. For example, assuming you have a Bean with the name of `webSecurity` that contains the following method signature:
>
> ```java
> public class WebSecurity {
>       public boolean check(Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
>               ...
>       }
> }
> ```
>
> You could refer to the method using:
>
> ```xml
> <http>
>   <intercept-url pattern="/user/**"
>       access="@webSecurity.check(authentication,request)"/>
>   ...
> </http>
> ```
>
> or in Java configuration
>
> ```java
> http
>       .authorizeRequests()
>               .antMatchers("/user/**").access("@webSecurity.check(authentication,request)")
>               ...
> ```

Comment: So the _SpEL_ at OP's controller method would be same: `@webSecurity.check(authentication, request)` ?

Comment: @hc_dev: It would be `@PreAuthorize("@accessBean.getPermision()")`.