# Can I access the current Session via Spring EL in Spring @PostAuthorize?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-el

How can I access the current HttpSession in a Spring `@PostAuthorize(...)` annotation?

I've read https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/authorization.html#el-access and at least request (HttpServletRequest) is mentioned and that object should contain a reference to the current session.

All variants of "#session", "#httpSession", "request" etc are NULL though.

Comment: You could write your own method to get the session and then you could call that method in the annotation.

Comment: Yes, that's my current workaround as well. I was just wondering because HttpSession is injectible via @Autowired so it is a Spring Bean. Why can't I use it directly though?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673084/using-other-bean-and-method-in-spring-security-preauthorize