# Spring - Pass parameters in custom annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, aop

I have the following:

Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AuthorizeUserAspect {
  @Autowired
  PermissionService permissionService;

  @Around("@annotation(AuthorizeUser)")
  public Object authorize(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    ...
  }
}
```

Interface:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AuthorizeUser {
}
```

Controller:

```
  @GetMapping("/businesses/{businessId}/test")
  public ResponseEntity<List<BusinessDto>> getBusinessListAsClient(Principal jwtAuthUser, @PathVariable String businessId) throws Exception {
      ...
  }
```

I need to pass in the named parameters from the method signature, plus an additional custom permission parameter (READ / WRITE), so something like this:

```
  @AuthorizeUser(Principal jwtAuthUser, String businessId, permission = <Enum or String>)
  @GetMapping("/businesses/{businessId}/test")
```

Is this possible? I don't really care how it's done as long as I can get these values in my authorize function to use them.

I know I can do something like:

```
joinPoint.getArgs();
```

to get the parameters by position, but I want this to be more generic, and certain controllers can have different params as 1st and second for example, so that would not work, plus I have no idea
how to get the last value.

Note: The authorize is just an example, but I'd like to do this for other custom annotation parameters as well.

Comment: As an example, are you aware Spring Security's [@PreAuthorize expression can invoke a method on a bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673084/using-other-bean-and-method-in-spring-security-preauthorize)?

Comment: Feedback, please. Don't just ask questions but then not react to answers or comment, which is not very polite. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get parameter of custom annotation by aspect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70001680/how-to-get-parameter-of-custom-annotation-by-aspect)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read the Spring AOP manual. How about this?

```java
@Around("@annotation(authorizeUser)")
public Object authorize(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, AuthorizeUser authorizeUser)
```