# How to get parameter of custom annotation by aspect?

Tags: java, aop

In my aspect method, i need get value of name (param of custom annotation) `name = "unit test"`

**Method call by user:**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class Task {

    @CronLogger(name = "unit test")
    public void testCronLogger(String param) {
        log.info("testCronLogger ...");
    }

}
```

**custom annotation:**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface CronLogger {
   public String name() default "";
}
```

**Aspect method:**

```
@Aspect
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class CronLoggerAspect {
    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CronLoggerAspect.class);
    
    @Around("@annotation(CronLogger)")
    public Object trace(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object[] tab = joinPoint.getArgs();
        for (Object object : tab) {
            log.debug("CronLogger: {}", object);
        }
       return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

**Console:**

```
CronLogger: test
testCronLogger ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (untested, I simply modified your code)?

```java
@Around("@annotation(cronLogger)")
public Object trace(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, CronLogger cronLogger) throws Throwable {
  log.debug("CronLogger: {}", cronLogger.name());
  return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

Please be careful with upper- and lower-case characters. One is an annotation class name, the other a method parameter name.

Comment: Yes, your solution is better than me. Careful with upper- and lower-case characters.

Answer (score 1):

need get Method and get Annotation of this method.

```
@Around("@annotation(CronLogger)")
public Object trace(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    String name = MethodSignature.class.cast(joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod().getAnnotation(CronLogger.class)
            .name();
    log.debug("CronLogger: {}", name);
    return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

Comment: I think you can define your advice as `public Object trace(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, CronLogger aspect)`. Then in the method you can just `aspect.name()` to access the property

Comment: @jms, your solution seems simpler but there is the following error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut `

Comment: Can you try changing `@Around("@annotation(CronLogger)")` to `@Around("@annotation(aspect)")` ? Make sure the method argument name matches the annotation name.

Comment: No, not like this. This reflection stuff is not just ugly but also unnecessary.